# JSF enable/disable commandLink depending on filling two inputText and boolean flag without javaScript

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to enable/disable a commandLink depending more than one condition.

At the beginning the commandLink is disabled. To enable it, I must click on a commandButton that activates a boolean flag (this point is currently working) and two inputText must be filled.

**CommandLink:**

```
<p:commandLink id="buttonGuardar" action="#{vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.buttonGuardar}" update="@form" process="@form" styleClass="fa-commandlink fa-floppy-o" immediate="true" disabled="#{vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.flagGuardar and empty vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.vinculacionLaboral.denominacionCas and empty vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.vinculacionLaboral.denominacionVal}">

  <h:outputText value="#{msg.guardar}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

**commandButton** that returns a boolean flag from the controller:

```
<p:commandButton id="validacionesValidarCodigoButton" actionListener="#{vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.buttonValidar}" value="Validar" styleClass="searchButton" icon="fa fa-button fa-check-circle" process="@form" style="margin-left: 20px;" update="buttonGuardar">
</p:commandButton>
```

**inputText:**

```
<p:row>
  <p:column styleClass="alignTextRight">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.vinculaciones_gestion_detalle_denominacionCas}" for="inputDenominacionCas" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column>
    <p:inputText id="inputDenominacionCas" style="width:100%" value="#{vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.vinculacionLaboral.denominacionCas}" />
  </p:column>
</p:row>

<p:row>
  <p:column styleClass="alignTextRight">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.vinculaciones_gestion_detalle_denominacionVal}" for="inputDenominacionVal" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column>
    <p:inputText id="inputDenominacionVal" style="width:100%" value="#{vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.vinculacionLaboral.denominacionVal}" />
  </p:column>
</p:row>
```

As you can see, I have tried using more than two conditions on disable property of commandLink:

```
disabled="#{vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.flagGuardar and not empty vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.vinculacionLaboral.denominacionCas and not empty vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.vinculacionLaboral.denominacionVal}"
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Does your 'disabled' EL show the expected values when just used as the value of an `h:outputText`?

Comment: Sorry @Kikeltje, but I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: You must use ajax listener that will listen to the changes on inputTexts and then will update the commandLink.

Comment: `<h:outputText value="EL FROM DISABLED ATTRIBUTE HERE"/>`

Comment: @Kukeltje do you mean that?  <h:outputText value="#{{vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.flagGuardar and not empty vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.vinculacionLaboral.denominacionCas and not empty vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.vinculacionLaboral.denominacionVal}" />

Comment: @sunofkyuss what event do I use? Thank you

Comment: Take a look at this showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/event.xhtml

Comment: Thanks @sunofkyuss , but these events doesn't force enable/disable the commandLink when the textLink is empty/filled

Comment: Yes, that's an example usage. Change outputText that in the example with your commandLink.

Comment: Thank you @sunofkyuss but it is not so simple. I have three conditions to enable the commandLink. First, my commandButton calls the controller that returns a boolean flag. Then, I need both inputText filled. I don't know how to fulfill all the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, logical operations that in "disabled" attribute are wrong. As I understood, you want to enable the link when flag is true and inputTexts are not empty.

```
enabled="#{flag and not empty inputText1 and not empty inputText2}"
```

Oh no, commandLink doesn't have enabled attribute. No problem:

```
disabled="#{not (flag and not empty inputText1 and not empty inputText2)}"
```

Now the changes at the values of inputTexts must trigger an ajax event that will update the commandLink.

```
<p:row>
  <p:column styleClass="alignTextRight">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.vinculaciones_gestion_detalle_denominacionCas}" for="inputDenominacionCas" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column>
    <p:inputText id="inputDenominacionCas" style="width:100%" value="#{vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.vinculacionLaboral.denominacionCas}" >
        <p:ajax event="keyup" update="buttonGuardar"/> 
    </p:inputText>
  </p:column>
</p:row>

<p:row>
  <p:column styleClass="alignTextRight">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.vinculaciones_gestion_detalle_denominacionVal}" for="inputDenominacionVal" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column>
    <p:inputText id="inputDenominacionVal" style="width:100%" value="#{vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.vinculacionLaboral.denominacionVal}" >
        <p:ajax event="keyup" update="buttonGuardar"/> 
    </p:inputText>
  </p:column>
</p:row>
```

If you want ajax event get triggered only when inputText lose focus, you can use "blur" event instead of "keyup".

Comment: Try without button and its flag. See if events work or not.

Comment: not working even without the button and its flag. Maybe a syntax mistake in "disabled" attribute ? Thank you.

Comment: Well, you must replace made up variables with your original ones. Dİd you?

Comment: Yes, I did. But still not wrking...Thank you!

Comment: Nothing. I have tried this option too: disabled="#{!(categoriasGestionDetalleController.flagGuardar and !empty inputDenominacionCas and !empty inputDenominacionVal)}"

Comment: They are vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.vinculacionLaboral.denominacionCas and vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.vinculacionLaboral.denominacionVal in question.